# SourceSafe backup script - best approach?

Tags: command-line, powershell, backup, batch-file, visual-sourcesafe

I was wondering what the best approach might be for creating a backup of my organisation's SourceSafe database, and moving it to a share on another server? Currently we have a scheduled job which runs a batch file, which in turn executes a PowerShell script.

This Powershell script creates a backup file (using SourceSafe command-line arguments), moves it to a new server (via a drive that has been mapped on the SourceSafe server), and sends the output of the SourceSafe backup to our administrator via e-mail.

This process *works* for the most part, but I can't help but feel there are more streamlined approaches or tools we should be utilizing. Any advice is welcomed!

Comment: best advice I can give is move to a repository other than SourceSafe! :)

Comment: Isn't a sourcesafe repo just a collection of files on a windows share? Can't you just use normal filesystem backup tools?

Comment: @skaffman, you are right. That is how we are doing it (until our migration to TFS is complete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSARC is not really a backup tool.  I wouldn't recommend it.  It's more like a way to cut-n-paste segments of a VSS repository between different databases.  It's also not without side effects.  At minimum, items in the source database get marked as archived.  At worst, they get deleted.

The best way is to take your DB offline, zip it up (or RAR, whatever), and copy the *.zip file somewhere safe.  VSS was designed back in the days when file sharing was the only cross-platform protocol reliably available on PC LANs, so the filesystem *is* the database.  Compared to modern client-server systems, VSS architecture has many flaws which I'm sure you're aware of -- but you may as well use its convenience to your advantage.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [SSARC](http://jeays.net/files/vss-ssarc-ssrestor.htm)- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9d14fh1(VS.80).aspx, but do look at moving away from SourceSafe!

Comment: We already use the SSARC utility :) I should have made that clear in my original post. We have been looking into Team Foundation Server for the past six months, but we won't come close to making any decision for at least another six!

Comment: OK. I've moved from VSS to TFS. TFS is much better. Now I'm moving from TFS to Subversion, but I like both.

Answer (score 0):

We are doing it much like you stated but are also taking it offline every night and checking integrity.  It's been working great for several years for us.